# Android emulator using more memory than it should

Tags: android, linux, emulation, android-virtual-device

I've provided the screenshot below. Even after I explicitly launched my android emulator
with -memory 256, my android emulator is using about 1GB of memory. How do I fix that?

PS: I'm on Manjaro Linux btw

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's *emulating* a 256MB Android device on your computer. The emulator program itself will also take a lot of memory.

Comment: I've added another screenshot check it out

Answer (score 0):

So first thing is your mistaking something , the RAM you chose for your emulator will be the software RAM not the RAM it costs in your PC that will be a different story, for example you have an 256  MB RAM but the emulator took 2Gig of your PC actual RAM.

The second thing is your second picture, i mean the picture is from the memory , the hard disk of your phone where you actully save thing not the RAM! That's different story on android that 1 Gig is just internal storage.

Comment: So how do I reduce the amount of memory consumed by the emulator ?

Comment: I am sure you can do it in the setting of your emulator.